# Dynamically pass argument to overload of function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamic

Is there any alternative to this?

```cs
    public static byte[] CreatePacket(params object[] any)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            foreach (object o in any)
                switch (o)
                {
                    case int:
                        writer.Write((int)o); break;
                    case string:
                        writer.Write((string)o); break;
                    case float:
                        writer.Write((float)o); break;
                    case double:
                        writer.Write((double)o); break;
                    case decimal:
                        writer.Write((decimal)o); break;
                    case byte:
                        writer.Write((byte)o); break;
                    case short:
                        writer.Write((short)o); break;
                    case ushort:
                        writer.Write((ushort)o); break;
                }
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I tried using `(dynamic)o` inside of `writer.Write();` but I'm getting this error:

> Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

I'm using Unity for this.

Is there any way to automatically pass the parameters from the function into the `Write` method, which has like 20 overloads, without actually checking for the allowed types?

Comment: You could get rid of the explicit casts with a _pattern matching_ `switch` like: `case int myInt: writer.Write(myInt); break;` Under the covers, it's likely the same code, but the pattern matching version is easier to read (to my eyes) and less error-prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you've done it is probably the "best" way to do it. You could use reflection to find the appropriate override based on the runtime type and call it, but it's going to be slower and make your code harder to read.

For the sake of discussion, here's how you would do it with reflection:

```cs
static byte[] CreatePacket(params object[] any) {
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]))
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
        foreach (object o in any) {
            var type = o.GetType();
            var method = GetWriteMethodForType(type);
            if (method is null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempted to write unsupported type to stream");
            }
            
            method.Invoke(writer, new object?[] { o });
        }
        
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

static MethodInfo? GetWriteMethodForType(Type type) {
    var binaryWriterType = typeof(BinaryWriter);
    var writerMethod = binaryWriterType.GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { type });
    return writerMethod;
}
```

---

To add a bit more info alongside the other answer explaining how to make `dynamic` work, here's what an implementation using `dynamic` would look like. I'm not a huge fan of `dynamic` because it tends to make code a bit more obscure, but it is a lot better than the reflection solution and in this case you may decide this is the way to go.

```cs
static byte[] CreatePacket(params dynamic[] any) {
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]))
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
        foreach (dynamic o in any) {
            writer.Write(o);
        }

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Also - if you pass an argument to `CreatePacket` that cannot be passed to `Write`, the exception you get won't be very clear when you're trying to debug it 6 months later..

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(bool)' has some invalid arguments
```

You may want to catch the `RuntimeBinderException` and throw your own exception.

Answer (score 2):

That error is occurring because you're using the `dynamic` keyword with a **.Net Compatibility Level** that does not support it.

Change the **Compatibility Level** to `.Net 4.x (.Net Framework)` in your **Project Settings > Player Settings**, if you need to use the `dynamic` keyword.

More information [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html).